# posting data from javascript to php is not working

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a code that sends email from php with an attachment. And here is my code.

my main.php file

```
 <form action="javascript:postData()" id="form">

<fieldset>

<!-- Form Name -->
<legend>Application</legend>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="Full Name">Full Name</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="FullName" name="FullName" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md">
    
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="Email">Email</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="Email" name="Email" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md">
    
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="roleFor">Role Applying for</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="roleFor" name="roleFor" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md">
    
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="jobId">Job ID</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="jobId" name="jobId" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md">
    
  </div>
</div>

<!-- File Button --> 
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="uploadResume">Upload Resume</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Textarea -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="experience">Experience</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">                     
    <textarea class="form-control" id="experience" name="experience"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Button -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="submit"></label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <button id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
```

and my js is

```
function postData() {
    const form = document.getElementById('form');
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('FullName', form.FullName.value);
    data.append('Email', form.Email.value);
    data.append('roleFor', form.roleFor.value);
    data.append('jobId', form.jobId.value);
    data.append('experience', form.experience.value);

    fetch('sendEmail.php', {method: 'POST', body: data}).then(response => {
        if (!response.ok){
            throw new Error('Network response was not ok.');
        } else 
        {
            console.log(response);
            alert('New job posted');
            document.getElementById("form").reset();

        }
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

and my sendEmail.php is

```
<?php
$fName = $_POST['FullName'];
$emailAddr = $_POST['Email'];
$roleFor = $_POST['roleFor'];
$jobId = $_POST['jobId'];
$exp = $_POST['experience'];

if (!empty($fName) && !empty($emailAddr))
    {

       

        $statusMsg = '';
        if (isset($_FILES["file"]["name"]))
        {
            $emailAddr = $_POST['Email'];
            $fromemail = 'admin@admin.com';
            $subject = 'Teesst Syubect';
            $email_message = "<table><tr><td>Name: </td><td>" . $fName . "</td></tr> </table>";
            $email_message .= "Please find CV in the attachment";
            $semi_rand = md5(uniqid(time()));
            $headers = "From: " . $fromemail;
            $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

            $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

            if ($_FILES["file"]["name"] != "")
            {
                $strFilesName = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
                $strContent = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"])));

                $email_message .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type:text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $email_message .= "\n\n";

                $email_message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: application/octet-stream;\n" . " name=\"{$strFilesName}\"\n" .
                //"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
                //" filename=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
                "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $strContent .= "\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";
            }
            $toemail = "myEmail@gmail.com";

            if (mail($toemail, $subject, $email_message, $headers))
            {
                $statusMsg = "Email send successfully with attachment";
                header("Location:careers.php");
            }
            else
            {
                $statusMsg = "Not sent";
            }
        }

    }

    else
    {
        echo "Enter both Title and Desription";
        die();
    }
?>
```

Now the issues are,

when I do  `<form action="sendEmail.php" id="form" method="post">`, it is sending the email as expected, but when I try to post it through javascript (as shown in my code), it isn't sending an email, but to my surprise, the response status is `200 OK`.

Please let me know where I'm going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: I have never seen `action="javascript:..."` being used. Have you tried `onsubmit="return postData()"` instead? Also make sure that your postData() function returns false, which will prevent the form from being submitted to the action url.

Comment: Instead of returning `false` in `postData()`, you can call `Event.preventDefault()` on the event-object of the `onsubmit`-event of the form. That might be cleaner, as it will loosen the coupling of HTML and JS.

Comment: Hi @LupinityLabs, I'm posting to php

Comment: Thanks for the tip @OskarGrosser